# Spectrum of the Cayley Graph

Tags: group-theory, characters, spectral-graph-theory

From wikipedia:

"Every group character $\chi$ of the group $G$ induces an eigenvector of the adjacency matrix of $\mathcal{C}(G,S)$. The associated eigenvalue is $\sum_{s \in S} \chi (s)$."

It seems false to me. Is it not true only for abelian G?

Comment: I just understood: with "character" wikipedia means (improperly, in my opinion) "linear character" here. With this remark, the claim is correct.